# Need to replace the values in Pandas according to frequency of occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

My challenge is to give a generic id to VENDOR ID according to the frequency of occurrence.

```
BaseData.groupby(["VENDOR_ID"]).size().sort_values(ascending=False,na_position='last')
```

returns the following.

```
VENDOR_ID
1111    5000
1112    4500
1113    4000
1114    3500
1115    3000
1116     880
1117     500
1118     300
1119     200
1120      20
```

Left column is the Vendor id and right column is the frequency of occurrence.
I want to retain the vendor id for the first 5 most frequently occurring Vendor ids. For all the remaining vendor ids, i want to replace the existing vendors ids to a generic vendor id 9999.

Any help in getting this done is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map` the 5 largest vendors to themselves, which will map the rest to `NaN` and then `.fillna` with the generic value:

```
df['VENDOR_ID'] = df.VENDOR_ID.map(
                      dict((i, i) for i in df.groupby('VENDOR_ID').size().nlargest(5).index)
                  ).fillna('9999')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it for you

```
new = BaseData.groupby(["VENDOR_ID"]).size().sort_values(ascending=False,na_position='last')
new = new.reset_index()
new.iloc[5:, 0] = 9999
```

Comment: you're missing the re-index

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to make the change directly in the original dataframe BaseData?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 vendor_id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 frequency = [5000,4000,3000,3500,880,500,400,300,300]

 df = pd.DataFrame({'vendor_id':vendor_id, 'frequency':frequency})
 df = df.sort_values('frequency', ascending=False)
 fifth_frequency = df.iloc[4]['frequency']    


 df['vendor_id'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[1]>=fifth_frequency else 9999, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let

```
i = BaseData.groupby(["VENDOR_ID"]).size().sort_values(ascending=False,na_position='last')[5:]
BaseData[BaseData['VENDOR_ID'].isin(i)] = 9999
```

Comment: This doesn't work as i returns the following                                                          
1116     880
1117     500
1118     300
1119     200
1120      20                                                                                                                               Let me see if I can modify on top of this. Thanks a lot for the direction

Comment: Had assumed that you were working on a `Series`: Just include an `.index` before the `[5:]` to only get those.